# Typedef Template Class Pointer in*.cpp file

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, typedef

In my header I got a typedef for a external library template together with a function like:

```
#include "ExternalFancyLib.h"
class Fancy
{
public:

  //...

  typedef FancyClass<int , 3> FancyClassType;

  FancyClassType::Pointer FancyFunction ();
}
```

In my *.cpp file I got:

```
#include "Fancy.h"

FancyClassType::Pointer Fancy::FancyFunction()
{
  // do and return smth.
}
```

My always friendly compiler tells me that "::" must be followed by a class or namespace, referring to FancyClassType.

Any idea to solve this with elegance?

Cheers Usche

Comment: Please post the exact and complete compiler error

Comment: error C2653: 'FancyClassType' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: You should be quite explicit when you make a question and make sure to add the appropriate code. The initial description did not mention that the `typedef` is nested inside a class definition, which is the core issue. Writing good questions is more than half the way to getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FancyClassType` is defined inside your `Fancy` class, so you have to specify that, too:

```
Fancy::FancyClassType::Pointer Fancy::FancyFunction(){}
```

`FancyClassType::Pointer` is looked up using the current scope. Inside your class definition, this includes the definitions in `Fancy`. In your Cpp File, the name is resolved in the global scope, so it would render `::FancyClassType::Pointer` (neglecting namespaces here). This is not defined.

Comment: Ah ofc! Thanks! Thats awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that your `FancyClassType` needs to go in place of  `FancyClass<int , 3>` also, you need to reference the `Fancy::` when using your `typedef`

Your code in the cpp file should look like this:

```
#include "Fancy.h"

Fancy::FancyClassType::Pointer Fancy::FancyFunction (){
// do and return smth
}
```

Otherwise you are not actually calling the `typedef` you made.

Another way I can think of is adding `::Pointer` to the `typedef` you you only need to call

```
Fancy::FancyClassType Fancy::FancyFunction (){
    // do and return smth
    }
```

That's the best I can come up with... hope it helps